# DDEV Giving Error when using Composer Create

Tags: ddev

When trying to create a new Silverstripe 5 site using composer create, i get this error:

```
5demo ❯ ls -la                                                                                                                                                                                          ⏎
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   3 will  staff   96 30 Nov 08:54 .
drwxr-xr-x  21 will  staff  672 30 Nov 08:53 ..
drwxr-xr-x  20 will  staff  640 30 Nov 08:19 .ddev
5demo ❯ ddev composer create silverstripe/installer .  ^5.0 --no-install
Executing Composer command: [composer create-project silverstripe/installer . ^5.0 --no-install /tmp/ZPmReG]
 

                                                                                                       
  Too many arguments to "create-project" command, expected arguments "package" "directory" "version".  
                                                                                                       

create-project [-s|--stability STABILITY] [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--prefer-install PREFER-INSTALL] [--repository REPOSITORY] [--repository-url REPOSITORY-URL] [--add-repository] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [--no-secure-http] [--keep-vcs] [--remove-vcs] [--no-install] [--no-audit] [--audit-format AUDIT-FORMAT] [--ignore-platform-req IGNORE-PLATFORM-REQ] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--ask] [--] [<package> [<directory> [<version>]]]

Failed to create project:exit status 1, stderr=
```

My config is:

```
5demo ❯ cat .ddev/config.yaml                                                                                                                                                                           ⏎
name: 5demo
type: php
docroot: ""
php_version: "8.1"
webserver_type: nginx-fpm
router_http_port: "80"
router_https_port: "443"
xdebug_enabled: false
additional_hostnames: []
additional_fqdns: []
database:
  type: mariadb
  version: "10.4"
nfs_mount_enabled: false
mutagen_enabled: false
use_dns_when_possible: true
composer_version: "2"
web_environment: []
nodejs_version: "16"
```

And my ddev version is v1.22.5 - updated today.
My set up is OSX 13.5.2, using colima.

Checking mutagen gives:
5demo ❯ ddev mutagen status
Mutagen: ok: watching

How can I create the new project?

Comment: The bit that I dont understand / worry is causing it is the extra /tmp/ZPmReG ddev is adding to composer-create

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong args; with `ddev composer create` you don't add a path. The correct thing for you will be

```
ddev composer create silverstripe/installer  ^5.0 --no-install
```

Please take a look at the [Silverstripe Quickstart](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/quickstart/#silverstripe) in the docs, and [DDEV and Composer](https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/developer-tools/#ddev-and-composer) will probably help.

If you want to use classic usage in a subdirectory, for example, you can `ddev ssh` and `cd` to a subdirectory and `composer create-project <path>`

Comment: thanks @rfay - I tried without the path but i must have already broken it as it was giving the same error.  trying in a new dir and new ddev project works great.  And the new silverstripe project option is great! I didnt know that had been added.  Thanks for your help and a great project!